# External jar Files in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, database-connection

Im trying to import external jar files onto the JRE system library in Java Eclipse, but it creates a new file path called Referenced Libraries and imports it there, which is not what I want.
I am trying to do this to connect to the database, This is the code I have:

```
database()
{
    try{

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/white-house","root","");
                    stmt=con.prepareStatement("select * from staff where username=? and password=?");



       }
```

Any suggestion please..

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the project -> Build path -> Add external archives...
and choose your jar file

Answer (score 1):

Try to right click your project and select properties then there is a place to add libraries - java build path - add jars.

Comment: I have done exactly as you have said, but it creates a new folder called Reference Lib and stores it in there.

Comment: yes you can then import classes that you need for your project.  Alternate approach is to right click on the project or source folder and pick import then Archive File and then select classes from jar you want to use.  This way it won't create a folder called REference Libs

Answer (score 0):

In the Eclipse Package Explorer, right-click your project, then select Build Path, then Configure Build Path, then click the Libraries tab and the Add External Jars button